# How to get Telegram InlineQuery-object?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I want to teach my bot to respond to an inline query. The problem is that to send a response to an inline query, you need to have certain request parameters (id and query text at least). But how to get these parameters? Where do I get them before I send answerInlineQuery to the Telegram server?

This issue is not covered in the documentation. I'm trying to extract these parameters from the result of the getUpdate-request:

```
def getUpdates (self):
        getup = URL + 'getUpdates'
        ...
        #some valid code to get update-JSON
        return url

def answerInlineQuery(self, inline_query_id, results):
        send = url + 'answerInlineQuery?inline_query_id=' + str(inline_query_id) + '&&' + 'results=' + results
        requests.get(send)
        ....

if (url != None) and ('inline_query' in url):
            inid = url['result'][0]['inline_query']['id']
            bot.set_inline_upd_id = int(inid) 
            fromid = url['result'][0]['inline_query']['fromid']
            query = url['result'][0]['inline_query']['query']
            if textMessage == '/modemscount':   
                r = requests.get('http://' + serverAddress + ':' + serverPort + '/api/v0/modem/')
                modemsDict = r.json() 
                message_text = str(len(modemsDict['modems']))
                inline_query_id = bot.inline_upd_id 
                results = json.dumps({'type':article, 'input_message_content':{'message_text':message_text}, 'id':1, 'title':count})
                bot.answerInlineQuery(inline_query_id, results)
```

But this code does not work. There are no error messages. Just when the user writes inline query, the bot does not react at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can get these `query` and `id` by the same way you [get updates](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getting-updates). So make sure your `getUpdates` really work.  Maybe you set a webhook and `getUpdates` don't return updates anymore? In this case remove webhook.

Comment: getUpdates really work, because the bot responds to simple requests. Webhooks are not used. /setinlines installed. But when I write an inline query in a chat with a random user and check it (even without code, simply via url-query), the 'inline_query' key does not appear in the JSON-object returned by getUpdates.

Comment: I just made a new bot and It worked as expected.  Message updates are like `{ "update_id": "...", "message": "..." }` and inline updates are like `{ "update_id": "..", "inline_query" : "..." }`

Comment: Yes, this is the solution to the problem. Thank you so much! After creating a similar bot, replacing only the token, I get the correct InlineQuery-object.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** create a new similar bot, replacing only the token. InlineQuery-mod will work correctly.
(This was my first bot. Perhaps, this explains its abnormal behavior.)